# Как работать с выражениями {val} в @GetMapping("/{val}") в spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

При работе с Spring столкнулся с таким синтаксисом `{val}` в мапинге. Вот такой метод:

```
@GetMapping("/next/{rId}")
public Object next(@PathVariable int rId, Principal user) {
    ...
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста, как начинает работать `@GetMapping`, если в его пути оказывается такое выражение, в фигурных скобках `{rId}`?

Какие запросы будут попадать на данный контроллер?

Как правильно вызывать такой контроллер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В контроллер будут попадать все запросы начинающиеся с `/next/` и имеющие число на месте `{rId}`. Это число будет автоматически внедрятся в одноимённый аргумент контроллера аннотированный `@PathVariable`.